# Нужна ли запятая: "Доставка на следующий день после заказа(,) с 12.00."?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

Нужна ли запятая в предложении?

Здесь однородные или неоднородные члены?

Answer (score 3):

День и время не являются однородными членами предложения. С этой точки зрения запятая не нужна. Однако автор может считать информацию о времени доставки второстепенной, уточняющей, и показать это с помощью запятой. Ввиду распространенности первого обстоятельства ("на следующий день после заказа"), после него должна следовать пауза — это еще один аргумент в пользу постановки запятой.

И еще. Принято показывать часы и минуты через двоеточие (например, 12:00).

Answer (score 0):

Это деловая речь с необходимой для покупателя информацией, поэтому лучше использовать вариант без запятой (неоднородные члены без уточнения):

**Доставка на следующий день после заказа с 12:00.**